# What's the best practice to take black & white pictures with a digital camera?

Tags: post-processing, black-and-white

I have a D40 camera. When I plan to take pictures that I want to be B/W, what is the best practice?

The truth is that there is a "command line" in the "tool menu" of the camera that transforms the picture taken to B/W, but the result is really not nice. There is almost no contrast, etc... I doesn't look like a BW picture at all. So my guess is that there are some tricks to take pictures that will end in B/W, isn't it?

Comment: Take a look at this recent question http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/black-and-white-photograph-in-camera-or-in-post

Comment: And for choosing black and white vs. color, see: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1757/when-is-black-and-white-likely-to-enhance-an-image

Comment: btw, I don't think this is a dupe

Comment: @Reid: can you clarify what's unique here? The answers (including yours!) suggest that it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 11):

The best way to take a black and white picture in a digital camera is to do the following.

1. Find a nice scene to photograph. Ideally, especially in black and white, you want a scene that will have a good level histogram from completely bright to completely black, and as many colors in between as possible.
2. Take the picture
3. Convert the picture in post. [Nik Siver Effects Pro](http://www.niksoftware.com/silverefexpro/usa/entry.php) is the pro version, if you don't have the budget, try Picasa. One nice thing about these tools is they will let you put in a "filter" that will give you some of the same effects that a black and white film photographer could do. That's really the subject for another question, but...

Comment: I decided to ask the question of what color filters can help to improve the appearance of a black and white photo, so take a look at http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/how-can-using-a-color-filter-help-to-improve-a-black-and-white-photo

Answer (score 8):

When I want to take a B&W photo I set my camera on a BW picture style and shoot RAW.
Why?
Because I can see on the back of my camera how the picture might look like and later in lightroom or any other RAW processing software I can decide exactly how my picture should look in BW.

Some other info here: http://www.northlight-images.co.uk/digital_black_white.html

Answer (score 4):

Best practice here is doing the conversion in post-processing, as you'll have the right controls to avoid the lame result you're getting in-camera. So, you will want to shoot in RAW and then find your way to [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3361/tips-for-making-black-and-white-conversions-in-post-processing). :)