# What's the best way to shoot Black and White images on a 600D / Rebel T3i

Tags: raw, black-and-white, camera-settings, canon-600d

I would like to shoot black and white images using my 600D / Rebel T3i. I would like the LCD to display a black and white image, but I would like to capture the image as a full-colour RAW file.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best practice to take black & white pictures with a digital camera?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7412/whats-the-best-practice-to-take-black-white-pictures-with-a-digital-camera)

Comment: This question seems more about the rear LCD than the best way to shoot B&W, not sure though...

Comment: Voted not a duplicate - this question is more specific - it's specifically about putting the camera in black and white mode but shooting RAW (so you can still get the full colour image later).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set a black and white picture style but keep the file type set to raw. See this post for more information: [Do different "Picture styles" affect RAW output?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13271/do-different-picture-styles-affect-raw-output)

Comment: Be aware that many photo processing programs display thumbnails of RAW images using the preview JPEG generated in-camera that is displayed on the LCD screen. If this is the case, then the thumbnails will display as monochrome, but the full file will still have the color information when opened. Some programs will allow you to select whether to display the preview jpeg from the camera or generate a new thumbnail when the folder is opened (be prepared to wait if there are a large number of files in the folder using the generate new thumbnail option).

Answer (score 0):

The canon EOS 600D has an option, in the AV mode, to change the camera from colour to black and white (I.E monochrome). This will also allow you to enable it for shooting in RAW, JPEGs, or both at the same time.

Comment: The same is true when using P, Tv, Av, M or B mode.